# How to use combineLatest where one of the streams is dependent of one of the others?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, combinelatest

I have an Angular-resolver that fetch data from the backend. I have the following calls to perform:

```
GetProject(projectId): Observable<IProject>
GetSites(projectId): Observable<ISites[]>
GetPersons(siteId): Observable<IPerson[]>
```

I'm trying to use combineLatest but not sure how to use RxJs in my scenario. I want all request to complete before resolving, but GetPersons() should have the id of the first item in GetSites() result as input. How is this done?

Comment: `combineLatest` should be for hot observables. For cold ones, you should use `forkJoin`. Also, it's not suited for related observables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks more like you want to just concat several calls:

```
forkJoin([GetProject(projectId), GetSites(projectId)]).pipe(
  concatMap(([project, sites]) => {
    const siteId = /* whatever here */;
    return GetPersons(siteId);
  }),
).subscribe(...);
```

It also depends on whether you want to receive in the observer all responses or just the last one. If you want all responses then you'll need to chain `GetPersons` with `map` and append the first two responses:

```
GetPersons(siteId).pipe(
  map(persons => [project, sites, persons]),
)
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I need to create a resolved-object to return to the router. I want something like: return new ResolvedData(project, sites, persons);

Comment: You can do that inside the `map` operator instead of returning an array.

Answer (score 2):

Create a replay subject :

```
const sub = new ReplaySubject(3);
```

Then make your calls

```
this.getProject(1).pipe(
  tap(project => sub.next(project)),
  switchMap(project => this.getSites(1)),
  tap(sites => sub.next(sites)),
  switchMap(sites => this.getPersons(sites[0].id)),
  tap(person => sub.next(person))
);
```

Your replay subject will contain the project as first value, the sites as second value, the person as thrid value.

You can do it with the `combineLatest` format with a `BehaviorSubject`.

```
const obs = new BehaviorSubject([]);
const add = val => obs.pipe(
  take(1),
  map(v => ([...v, val]))
).subscribe(v => obs.next(v));

this.getProject(1).pipe(
  tap(project => add(project)),
  switchMap(project => this.getSites(1)),
  tap(sites => add(sites)),
  switchMap(sites => this.getPersons(sites[0].id)),
  tap(person => add(person))
);
```

This time, the value returned will be an array of all of your values.

Finally, you have the complicated syntax to concatenate them, without a subject.

```
this.getProject(1).pipe(
  switchMap(project => this.getSites(1).pipe(map(sites => ([project, sites])))),
  switchMap(([project, sites]) => this.getPersons(sites[0].id).pipe(map(person => ([project, sites, map])))),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.project$ = this.myService.getProject(projectId);
this.sites$ = this.myService.getSites(projectId);
this.persons$ = this.sites$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    (sites: ISites[]) => merge(...sites.map((site: ISites) => this.myService.getPersons(site.id))),
  ),
); // that should result in Observable<IPerson[][]>, you likely need to flatten it
```